# generation a nested matrix with a partly comparison of two other nested matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

(this problem is maybe challenging because of its partly comparison) 
there are two nested matrices:
mainmatrix1:

```
mainmatrix1={{{1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, I}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2},{1, 2, 2, 
1, 8, 5, 5, 8, -I}}, {{3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, I}, {3, 4, 4, 3, 3,
 4, 4, 3, 1}, {3, 4, 4, 3, 8, 5, 5, 8, -1}}, {{8, 5, 5, 8, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4}
 , {8, 5, 5, 8, 3, 4, 4, 3, I}, {8, 5, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5, 8, 0}}};
```

and matrix2 as

```
matrix2 = {{{1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, I}, {3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 
 2}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 8, 5, 5, 8, -I}}, {{3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1,I},
 {1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1}, {3, 4, 4, 3, 8, 5, 5,8, -1}},
 {{8, 5, 5, 8, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4}, {8, 5, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5, 8,I}, {8, 5, 5, 8, 3, 4, 4, 3, 0}}};
```

(****** I have to have an algorithm that contains a creation of `finalmatrix` as a result of comparison between mainmatrix1 and matrix2 as: *******)

```
 Do[ comparison between sub_lists in mainmatrix1 and matrix2 just 8 of them

If[all eight elements are equals fill another matrix (finalmatrix) with the eight elements of mainmatrix1 and ninth from matrix2] 
  ,{i,1,9},{j,1,9}]
```

for the shape (I created manually):
mainmatrix1:

[image]

matrix2:

[image]

For example Do loop reaches at the Yellow Line. All eight elements are equal of Yellow one in matrix2, ninth elements of mainmatrix1 must be replaced from matrix2 `1-> 2`.

After that we receive to Red one of mainmatrix1 : `2->1` and so on
the finalmatrix:

```
finalmatrix = {{{1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, I}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 
 1}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 8, 5, 5, 8, -I}}, {{3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
 I}, {3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2}, {3, 4, 4, 3, 8, 5, 5, 
 8, -1}}, {{8, 5, 5, 8, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4}, {8, 5, 5, 8, 3, 4, 4, 3, 
 0}, {8, 5, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5, 8, I}}};
```

[image]

Comment: It is always more readable when the example is minimal. So matrices with 2x2x3 dimensions would be enough. Moreover, what's the rule,  we should scan through matrix2 for each element in matrix1? Because I don't know how your yellow line in matrix1 is related to the yellow one in matrix2.

Comment: Eight elements of Yellow line (except ninth) in mainmatrix1 are equal to Eight elements of Yellow line in matrix2. I called 'mainmatrix1' because the eight elements are kept and ninth replaced. (if equality satisfied).

Comment: I know, but yellow lines are on positions 1,2 and 2,2 respectively in those matrices. Is there a pattern or is it how I said it is?

Comment: mainmatrix1 differs of matrix2. they have been created in two different process. some elements are completely equal correspondingly and coincidentally.  for example 1,1---1,3----2,1----2,3---3,1, for these elements   the finalmatrix has complete nine elements of each list of mainmatrix1 or matrix2 which are equal (all nine). but for different elements same as 1,2 of mainmatrix1, ninth must be replaced by ninth of equivalence of matrix2.

Comment: Actually, creating a finalmatrix is annoying and the process of generation matrix1 and matrix2 is not important.

Comment: @garej, and Kuba, So sorry for complicate the example, however the problem which I have to solve is more complicated unfortunately. The example was correct but I will try to write and elucidate a better example in order to use comments and answers of professional users (same as you) who have helped me very well since I came to SE. They are so nice and their answers have been so fruitful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if this is just a problem in indexing properly. If I understand the question, you can distinguish the indices where the ninth element needs to come from mainmatrix1 and where it needs to come from matrix2:

```
ind = Table[If[mainmatrix1[[i, j, 1 ;; 8]] == matrix2[[i, j, 1 ;; 8]], 1, 0], 
           {i, 1, Length[mainmatrix1]}, {j, 1, Length[mainmatrix1]}]
```

Now just use the indices to set the ninth element:

```
matrixfinal = mainmatrix1;
Table[If[ind[[i, j]] == 1, matrixfinal[[i, j]] = mainmatrix1[[i, j]], 
         matrixfinal[[i, j]] = matrix2[[i, j]]], 
         {i, 1, Length[mainmatrix1]}, {j, 1, Length[mainmatrix1]}]
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I did not see your post and as I had said (above comment) I posted an elucidated example in a new post. Please let me check your answer in order to see its results.

Comment: Related link is [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104249/partial-comparison-between-lists-contained-in-larger-matrices)