# Partial comparison between lists contained in larger matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, code-review

Please presume we have two nested matrices m1 and m2:

```
m1 = {{{1, 2, 2, I}, {1, 1, -2, 1}, {3, 2, 2, -I}, {3, 4, 4, I}, {1, 
 1, 4, 1}, {3, 3, 4, -1}, {8, 5, 5, 4}}};
m2 = {{{0, 2, 2, I}, {3, 2, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 2, -I}, {3, 4, 4, I}, {2, 3,
  2, 1}, {2, 1, 2, 1}, {3, 3, 4, 1}}};
```

shapes are:
m1:

[image]

and m2:

[image]

What I am looking to do is this.  For any two sublists in m1 and m2, if the first 3 elements are common to both, then take replace the fourth element of the list in m1 with the corresponding element in m2.

Below I have written a code for partial comparison, but I wonder if there is a better way to do it, without the multiple comparisons using `&&` and the multiple nested `[[]]`,

```
Do[
     Do[

          If[m1[[1, i]][[1]] == m2[[1, j]][[1]] && 
               m1[[1, i]][[2]] == m2[[1, j]][[2]] && 
               m1[[1, i]][[3]] == m2[[1, j]][[3]],
       m1[[1, i]][[4]] = m2[[1, j]][[4]]
             ]          

            , {i, 1, 7}]

  , {j, 1, 7}]
```

This produces the desired result,

[image]

But for larger matrices the writing as `[[]][[]]` an `&&` repeatedly is confusing. Is there a way to write more directly a code to compare three elements of any list without writing separately for each of them and using `&&`?

Comment: You give a bad example because `m2` is such that there will be no change in `m1` after your comparison is made.

Comment: @m_goldberg, do not be too pushing in this case; OP seems to compare 'all-to-all', not "elememt-to-element" =))

Comment: Thanks for creating a minimal example. Please include desired result too.

Comment: @m_goldberg, garej and Kuba, thanks so much for your following my question, I right now see your comments and I do apologize for my delaying, I am posting the desired result, although I think the bill's answer is good.

Comment: @Ackaran, good to know that you have found your solution. For your case you do not need Spans, by the way, as you may use `Most` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To index into arrays and consider more than a single element, use `;;`. Thus you can deal with elements 2 through 7 of an array `x` with

```
x[[2;;7]]
```

Thus your three `&&` lines can be replaced by

```
If[m1[[1, i]][[1;;3]] == m2[[1, j]][[1;;3]] ...  ]
```

Please note that this is all perfectly well documented in the docs for `Part`.

Comment: I did not pay attention carefully at documents. Thank you and please let me check.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to compare all to all, use `Outer`.
Say, we have a function `h` with `[[Span]]`:

```
h = (#1[[1 ;; -2]] == #2[[1 ;; -2]]) &
```

Note, that `-2` suits the list of any length longer than 2. Than, with your data structure:

```
Outer[h, m1[[1]], m2[[1]], 1] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

We may get positions of `True`:

```
pos = Position[Outer[h, m1[[1]], m2[[1]], 1], _?TrueQ]
(* {{3, 2}, {4, 4}, {6, 7}} *)
```

This position can be transformed in replacement form:

```
rep = pos /. {x_, y_} :> x-> m2[[1]][[y]]
(* {3 -> {3, 2, 2, 1}, 4 -> {3, 4, 4, I}, 6 -> {3, 3, 4, 1}} *)
```

Replacement:

```
ReplacePart[m1[[1]], rep]
```

> {{1, 2, 2, I}, {1, 1, -2, 1}, {3, 2, 2, **1**}, {3, 4, 4, **I**}, {1, 1, 4, 1}, {3, 3, 4, **1**}, {8, 5, 5, 4}}